# PostgreSql propagate changes across databases

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm a newbie to databases and i'm facing what seems a simple problem.
i have and old database **db_a** contains a table **table_a** and i want to use this table in a new database **db_b**.
i found out that Referential integrity across databases in PostgreSql is not a good practice. So the solution was to copy the table **table_a** to **db_b** and use referential integrity.

So far so good!

The problem now is: i want to always update the new table in **db_b** with any changes in the old table in **db_a**. So the two tables will remain similar all over the time.

What is the best solution for such a classic issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic solution would be to use [multiple schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) (as in [create schema...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html)) instead of multiple databases. Foreign key references, including `on update cascade` and `on delete cascade` just work. You can [alter default privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for each schema if you need to.

Comment: what about using  dblink or FDW in a trigger function to send changed data to the new table?

Comment: You can do just about anything in a trigger. I don't know your application, though, so using standard SQL foreign key constraints within a single database seems to make more sense. If the tables are meant to be used together, they probably belong in the same database. If the tables are *not* meant to be used together, then stop doing that. :-)

Comment: i want to have the same table in two different databases to deal with separation of concerns issue. So triggers across databses is better or two schemas in one database is better?

Comment: Two schemas in one database. (Multiple schemas is fine for separating concerns. I have the hstore extension in the schema "hst", for example.)